# Nature of critical points for given non-linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find the nature of the critical points of the following system:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-y^2-1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2y$$
I have found the critical points are $(\pm 1,0)$.

The system is non-linear, how to find the nature of the critical points for this system ?

Comment: computing the eigenvalues for the Jacobian matrices at those points is a good start

Comment: @peek-a-boo for the point $(1,0)$, eigen vaues are $2$ and $2$. That is real and equal. So $(1,0)$ is NODE and UNSTABLE. Is it correct ?

Comment: right, both positive eigenvalues implies unstable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, the Jacobian is

$$
J =
\begin{pmatrix}
2x & -2y \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the critical points are located at $(x, y) = (\pm 1, 0)$

> Analysis at $(1, 0)$

Eigenvalues are $2$ with eigenvector $\hat{x}$, and $2$ with eigenvector $\hat{y}$. That is an *unstable* node

> Analysis at $(-1, 0)$

Eigenvalues are $-2$ with eigenvector $\hat{x}$, and $+2$ with eigenvector $\hat{y}$. That is a *saddle point*, where the stable manifold runs along the $x$ axis and the unstable one runs along the $y$ axis.

Here's a little sktech

[image]

And if you want to reproduce it (`python`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 2, 20), np.linspace(-2, 2, 20))
dx = x ** 2 - y ** 2 - 1
dy = 2 * y
plt.quiver(x, y, dx, dy)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the nature of the critical points for a non-linear system, you can use the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix evaluated at the critical points. The Jacobian matrix is a matrix of partial derivatives of the system with respect to x and y.

For the system you provided, the Jacobian matrix is:
J={{2x, -2y}, {0, 2}}

Evaluating the Jacobian matrix at the critical points (±1,0) gives:
J(1,0) = {{2,0}, {0,2}}
J(-1,0) = {{-2,0}, {0,2}}

The eigenvalues of J(1,0) are 2 and 2, which are both positive. This means that the critical point (1,0) is a stable spiral point. The eigenvalues of J(-1,0) are -2 and 2, which means that the critical point (-1,0) is a saddle point.

In general, if the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are both positive at a critical point, the critical point is a stable spiral point. If the eigenvalues are both negative, the critical point is an unstable spiral point. If one eigenvalue is positive and the other is negative, the critical point is a saddle point.

So in this case, the critical points (±1,0) are a stable spiral point and a saddle point respectively.

Comment: you're mixing up stable and unstable (e.g if eigenvalues are positive, then things move away from that point, so unstable)